# How to prevent clang-format from adding a newline before #define lists

Tags: c++, clang-format

What I'm trying to do:

```
#define NEOPIXEL_BKGD_COLOR { 255, 255, 255, 0 }  // R, G, B, W
```

What clang-format is forcing on me:

```
#define NEOPIXEL_BKGD_COLOR \
{ 255, 255, 255, 0 }           // R, G, B, W
```

How do I prevent clang from adding that newline?

Here is my current clang config, although I've tried just about every option I know of:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM, 
IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash, 
ColumnLimit: 0, 
AlignConsecutiveMacros: AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments, 
AlignTrailingComments: true, 
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2, 
IndentWidth: 2, 
TabWidth: 2, 
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1, 
PointerAlignment:  Right, 
SortIncludes: false, 
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: AcrossComments, 
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
```